# Retrieving i18n data with fallback language

Tags: sql, postgresql, internationalization, fallback

I have to grab i18n text from a database. The default language is English, it has text for *everything*. But the non-English languages doesn't necessarily have all the desired translations. If a non-English translation for a certain entity/key isn't available in the DB, then I'd like to have it to return the English text instead. So, English is the *fallback* language here.

The i18n text table look like so (PostgreSQL dialect):

```
CREATE TABLE translation (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    language_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    key VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT translation_unique UNIQUE (language_code, key)
)
```

The data look like this:

```
INSERT INTO translation 
    (language_code, key, value) 
VALUES
    ('en', 'foo', 'foo in English'),
    ('nl', 'foo', 'foo in Nederlands (Dutch)'),
    ('en', 'bar', 'bar in English')
```

I'd like to basically do the below pseudo SQL query:

```
SELECT key, value 
FROM translation 
WHERE (language_code = 'nl' OR IF value IS NULL THEN language_code = 'en')
```

*(actually, the `'nl'` value is to be parameterized)*

So that it returns the following:

```
+-----+---------------------------+
| key | value                     |
+-----+---------------------------+
| foo | foo in Nederlands (Dutch) |
| bar | bar in English            |
+-----+---------------------------+
```

How can I achieve this in a single SQL query?

The DB in question is PostgreSQL, but a RDMBS-agnostic way would be nice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT
    e.key,COALESCE(o.value,e.value)
    FROM Translation                e
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Translation o ON e.key=o.key and o.language_code='nl'
    WHERE e.language_code='en'
```