# SQL - Fallback to default language when translate does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, internationalization

Recording texts in different languages in a table (tbl_i18n) with the following structure:

```
text_FK | language_FK | value
-----------------------------
    1   |       1     | hello
    1   |       2     | hallo
    2   |       1     | world
    3   |       1     | test
```

gives texts of a specific language (id = 2) with a simple join like:

```
SELECT [value] FROM tbl_i18n i
   JOIN tbl_products p ON p.text_id = i.text_FK
   JOIN tbl_languages l ON l.id = i.language_FK AND i.language FK = 2;
```

and the result is:

```
 value
-------
 hallo
```

How could aforementioned select statement changed so we could have got a default language and when translate for a text fields does not exist their fallback text will be shown and the result will became:

```
 value
-------
 hallo
 world
 test
```

Comment: Can you modify the question for better understanding?

Comment: Also check this question to see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238651/retrieving-i18n-data-with-fallback-language?rq=1

Comment: @lostmylogin, here we've got 3 textfields and 4 records. 3 in english and 1 in german. hello field has a german translation but others dont. i want to get all fields in german but when there is no german translation english fields should be returned. Tanx for the link; looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` the language table twice. The first time for wanted language, the second time for fallback value. Use `COALESCE` to pick wanted language if available, otherwise fallback language.

```
SELECT coalesce(l1.[value], l2.[value])
FROM tbl_i18n i
JOIN tbl_products p ON p.text_id = i.text_FK
LEFT JOIN tbl_languages l1 ON l.id = i.language_FK AND i.language_FK = 2
LEFT JOIN tbl_languages l2 ON l.id = i.language_FK AND i.language_FK = 1;
```

Comment: Brief and precise. Tanx.

Comment: Is it possible to implement the approach without need to use COALESCE and to have only one language set alias, not l1, l2? Probably by using UNION.. I need to write universal method for different entities with selector parameters using Linq-to-SQL which sorts table data by localized text in other table.

Answer (score 0):

I think in simple english you want the highest available `language_FK` for each `text_FK`.

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY text_FK ORDER BY language_FK DESC)rn
FROM TableName 
)
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE X.rn = 1
```

Comment: Here i've just used `int` ids for simplicity; Actually we use `uniqueidentifier` as ids; so i am not sure we could use `ORDER BY`.